# hrtimer doesn't return negative values if expired

Tags: c, timer, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

```
timeval v = ktime_to_timeval(hrtimer_get_remaining(timer));
```

Instead of getting a negative value when the timer expires ( i expect ~ minus 100 ms ), i get like plus 800 ms, which is pretty off, and i cannot make any connection between the expected result and the actual.
My first taught was that either hrtimer_get_remaining or ktime_to_timeval are doing something wrong, so i've used ktime_to_timespec and hrtimer_expires_remaining, but the results were the same.

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Could you check your `v.tv_sec` ? Isn't it `-1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short unswer

Probably your getting proper results but your interpretation is wrong. Your code is only checking `tv_nsec` ignoring `tv_sec`, which probably holds `-1`. If you add `-1` second and a little bit more than `800ms`, you will get your ~`-100ms` value.

### Longer explaination

Even though `ns_to_timespec` is not calling `set_normalized_timespec` as it was some time ago, it still normalizes the timespec value in the same way. Here's the current version of this function:

```
struct timespec ns_to_timespec(const s64 nsec)
{
        struct timespec ts;
        s32 rem;

        if (!nsec)
                return (struct timespec) {0, 0};

        ts.tv_sec = div_s64_rem(nsec, NSEC_PER_SEC, &rem);
        if (unlikely(rem < 0)) {               // <-- here is normalization
                ts.tv_sec--;
                rem += NSEC_PER_SEC;
        }
        ts.tv_nsec = rem;

        return ts;
}
```

Just for the reference, couple years ago this normalization was done this way:

```
if (unlikely(nsec < 0))
    set_normalized_timespec(&ts, ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
```

I'm mentioning this because there is a comment just above `set_normalized_timespec` function saying:

```
Note: The tv_nsec part is always in the range of
0 <= tv_nsec < NSEC_PER_SEC
For negative values only the tv_sec field is negative !
```

This behavious is defined by POSIX standard. Here's for example [what it says](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) about errors you can get after issueing `nanosleep()` function (`rqtp` is of type `struct timespec *`):

```
[EINVAL]
  The rqtp argument specified a nanosecond value less than zero or greater than or equal to 1000 millio
```

And here's similar definition from [`nanosleep(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) Linux man page:

The structure timespec is used to specify intervals of time with nanosecond precision. It is defined as follows:

```
struct timespec {
    time_t tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long   tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};

The value of the nanoseconds field must be in the range 0 to 999999999.
```

Note that in both cases there is no information about negative `tv_sec` being invalid.

### Simple prove

Here's a simple kernel module that proves my point:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    struct timeval v = ktime_to_timeval((ktime_t){.tv64 = -200000000});
    printk(KERN_INFO "v= %ld, %ld\n", v.tv_sec, v.tv_usec);

    return -1;
}
```

After inserting it, here's the output from kernel log:

```
v= -1, 800000
```

Comment: It is a bit strange how the negative time values are interpreted.

Comment: If i print with %ld, for some timers i get values like -97, -128, -147 ( i don't really understand why, because those timers are not so old ). But, for the timer i care, that i should receive ~ -200 ms, indeed, i receive -1 for second and 800000 for microseconds. I don't know for sure if i should count on this further on, because i don't understand the other negative values.

Comment: @Cumatru: Maybe it is strange but this is how it is defined by POSIX standard. What do you mean about getting -97 when printing with %ld? What value do you actually print?